# Free groups as free product of infinite cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, direct-product, free-abelian-group, free-product

Let $S$ be an arbitrary set (countable or uncountable). It is clear that the free abelian group generated by $S$ is isomorphic to the direct sum

$$\bigoplus_{s\in S}\mathbb{Z}.$$

Is the free group generated by $S$ then isomorphic to

$$\ast_{s\in S}\mathbb{Z}$$
where $\ast$ denotes the free product of groups?

Comment: Yes, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is also the free group on 1 generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

It's a general pattern based on the free-forgetful adjunction: the free functor preserves colimits, in particular coproducts, so since $S=\coprod_{s\in S}1$ where $1$ is a set with one element, then
$$F(S)=\coprod_{s\in S}F(1)\,,$$
and the coproduct in the category of groups is free product and $F(1)=\Bbb Z$.